# Given a list of lists, find the index of the list which contains a particular item in Python

Tags: python, list, enumerate

For example, I have a list of lists:

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

Given element 3, I need the index of the list it belongs to, i.e. 1.

The lists have mutually exclusive elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick solution, although it does build a temporary list:

```
>>> x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
>>> v = 3
>>> [v in y for y in x].index(True)
1
>>>
```

Comment: How can we account for exceptions, e.g. if the element is not a part of any list?

Comment: In that case it will throw an exception, so you could wrap it in a try...except to catch it.  Alternatively, you could construct the list first (without the index), then check if `True in l`, then do the index only if it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

v= 89

t= [ v in y for y in x]

y = t.index(True) if any(t) else -1

print y
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for index, value in enumerate(lst):
    if desiredValue in value:
        print index
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation about what your answer is doing.  That way, the OP knows how to solve similar problems in the future, and other people can see why your answer solves the problem, and potentially understand where it may not be the solution they need.